# Code signing app bundle on OS X with Install4j 6, sealed resource is missing or invalid

Tags: macos, code-signing, install4j

I am having troubles producing a signed app bundle for OS X with Install4j 6. I have read the blog entry at http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2014/09/the-v2-signature-scheme-for-application.html and it lead me to believe that it is not possible to create a signed installer app (my client requires a few steps, including agreeing to a license) that installes a signed app.

Example:

1. User downloads MyApplication.dmg
2. User mounts it in Finder and clicks on "Install MyApplication.app"
3. User follows instructions in installer and application bundle ends up in /Application/MyApplication.app

The problem here is that if I use a *Single Bundle Installer*, only the 'Install MyApplication.app' (the installer) is signed. I can verify this with spctl.

```
$ spctl -a  -v /Volumes/<VOLNAME>/Install\ MyApplication.app
/Volumes/<VOLNAME>/Install MyApplication.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

The problem is, the app bundle itself is not signed, and I'm getting the annoying firewall popup, because the app has to open a TCP port.

```
$ spctl -a  -v /Applications/My\ Application.app
/Applications/My Application.app: rejected
source=no usable signature
```

So what I did is convert it to a *Single Bundle Archive*. What I then do is open the DMG, and drag the MyApplication.app to the /Applications folder. But then spctl still complains:

```
$ spctl -a  -v /Applications/My\ Application.app
/Applications/My Application.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? How do I fix that issue? And is it completely impossible to have a signed installer (i.e. something with a GUI wizard) that extracts a signed app bundle? Why does it need to modify the bundle anyway when installing it?

Comment: Are you trying to sign an `Installer product archive` or an `App bundle`, it's a bit unclear? Also please include the exact codesign command you are using and which type of codesigning certificate. Installer packages need to be signed a particular way, and that's provided it's a `pkg` or `mpkg` - from the looks of it that does not seem like the type of installer package you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is that if I use a Single Bundle Installer, only the >'Install MyApplication.app' (the installer) is signed

That is correct. It's technically not possible otherwise since there are variable runtime files in a contained directory (.install4j) that will break the signature. We would not add this media file type today, but we obviously cannot remove it.

It will get past gatekeeper, but if you need a signed application bundle, you have to use the single bundle archive or the folder installer.

> So what I did is convert it to a Single Bundle Archive. What I then do is >open the DMG, and drag the MyApplication.app to the /Applications folder. >But then spctl still complains:

That should not happen. Something must have modified a file in between. Try to sign a different installer like the "hello world" sample and check what happens in that case.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thank you for responding so quickly. I am glad to be talking to the definite authority on this one.

I understand that changing a file in the bundle will break the signature, what I don't understand is why it is necessary to do that in the first place? Would the simplest installer imaginable not simply copy an already pre-signed application bundle to /Applications?

Comment: The installer does not work that way in install4j, it installs all files separately, the final result is not known at compile time. It would be possible to think of a media file that does what you want but it would be very different from our installer concept. Also, a pre-signed application bundle does not need an installer on Mac OS X, it should be dragged to the final destination by the user. If there is an further configuration necessary you can do that on the first startup with a custom installer application.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to get the Single Bundle Archive to work, and add a license agreement to the DMG.

Comment: Hi Ingo, I tried to sign the hello world single bundle archive, and as expected it works just fine. Any idea how i can debug this issue for my own project, like maybe a magic flag that makes install4j log exactly what it is doing? Are there any common mistakes that can cause this?

Comment: Have you tried executing codesign --verify --verbose MyApp.app on the bundle?

Comment: Ingo, the problem was pretty subtle. I built a custom JRE bundle with some patched files (Unlimited Cryptography JCE extensions/export policy files). Those files had the quarantine bit set. What was really weird, is that the .app bundle verified fine when accessed through the DMG volume (/Volumes/MyApp/My App.app) but after being copied to disk, somehow those quarantine bits confused codesign:
/Applications/My app.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
file missing: /Applications/My App.app/Contents/Resources/jre.bundle/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/._local_policy.jar

Comment: After removing the quarantine attributes on the affected files (xattr -d com.apple.quarantine), repackaging the JRE bundle .tar.gz everything works fine now. Still, it doesn't explain why codesign thinks the .app bundle on the DMG volume is valid, but the one on disk isn't. Probably some filesystem issue.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot, you have been a great help to me.